# Is it an anti-pattern to create a new container for each object that is being collaborated upon?

Tags: fluid-framework

We are building an application that uses Fluid Framework, and the application creates a new container with a shared matrix the first time a user "opens" an application object for editing/viewing. Subsequent users who "open" the object will load the existing container created by the first user. There are lots (more than 1000) of distinct objects (ie. different id values) that can be opened concurrently, and each object is collaborated upon by some number of distinct users.

Is it an anti-pattern to create one container per object? Or should we explore using less containers (eg. one container for all objects, or one container for every 5 objects)?

I feel like it makes sense to have a single container for each object because if the container contained shared matrices for more than one object then the client would be needlessly downloading extra data because only one shared matrix would ever be used (ie. the shared matrix that applies to the object that was "opened").

That being said, we are concerned about the lifetime of the containers in the fluid service and how/if a large number of containers (and therefore memory) will eventually accumulate in the fluid service which we imagine will impact our ability to scale up and support large numbers of concurrent collaborative sessions.

Bonus questions:

- Do containers eventually get automatically "cleaned up" at some point?
- Is it possible to manually remove/delete a container from a fluid service?
- Is there any way to tell how many containers currently exist in the fluid service?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it an anti-pattern to create one container per object? Or should we explore using less containers (eg. one container for all objects, or one container for every 5 objects)?

I'm not sure it's an anti-pattern, but I think it's unnecessary. I think a better approach might be to use DataObject as the things users load. In other words, wrap your business logic for working with the SharedMatrix in a DataObject.

Instances of that DataObject will be loaded by the framework on demand. In other words, we virtualize the data model by loading DataObjects on demand when requested. The call requests a DataObject (ex root) but the loading of a DataObject is owned by the Fluid runtime itself.

However, note that there's currently no way to unload a DataObject -- only a Container. The lifecycle of DataObjects is under the Framework's control.

If you use this model, then you can still create multiple containers if needed. But you could also reimagine the container as the "object selection" UX. I.e. user visits a container and sees all the objects in the container, and when they select one, that DataObject (i.e. the SharedMatrix and accompanying business logic) is loaded.

For your other questions, container management of the type you're referring to is specific to the service implementation. For Azure Fluid Relay, you can use the Azure CLI to list and manage containers:

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-fluid-relay/how-tos/container-deletion.